# How to extend the space beetwen rows?

Tags: spacing

I want to make my latex file like in photo 1 {i want to make spaces beetwen rows.

[image: i want to make my latex file like in photo 1]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

{\center \section  {\bfseries Matricat} }
\subsection{\bfseries Shembulli i pare, Matrica} 
\begin{equation*}
\left(\begin{array}{c}a_{11}\quad a_{12}\quad \cdots\quad a_{1n} \\ a_{21}\quad  a_{22} \quad \cdots\quad  a_{2n} \\  \vdots\qquad \vdots \qquad \ddots \quad \vdots\\  a_{n1} \quad  a_{n2} \quad \cdots \quad  a_{nn} \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
Kjo matrice  eshte prodhua duke perdore  komanden  pmatrix makro~\cite{referenca1} ne blloqe begin[matrix]. Disa matrica jane te mundshme duke perdore komandat per mjediset apo environment-et: \\ \textbf{matrix}~\cite{referenca2}, \textbf{pmatrix}~\cite{referenca3}, \textbf{bmatrix}~\cite{referenca4}, \textbf{Bmatrix}~\cite{referenca5}, \textbf{vmatrix}~\cite{referenca6}, \textbf{Vmatrix}~\cite{referenca7}, te cilat prodhojne matricat si ne vijim ~\cite{referenca8}:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{matrix} r & s & t \\u & v & w \\x & y & z \end{matrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}r\quad s\quad t\\ u\quad v\quad w\\ x\quad y\quad z\end{pmatrix} \qquad \begin{bmatrix}r & s & t\\ u &v&w \\ x & y & z \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What did you try?

Comment: i search for this problem but i dont find anythig....

Comment: Could you post so we don't have to do all the typing?

Comment: how to post  my code is to lenght..

Comment: and than you expect that we should retype your code? please make minimal working example with show only your equation. documewnt had to be complete, beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: your code doesn't reproduce your image, so it is difficult to say, what is the problem. if you have in equation two lines, than after ` \\ ` add `[<desired vertical space>]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabular*` for this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for ç
\usepackage[albanian]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for tables
\usepackage{xpatch}   % for patching macros

% boldface section titles, not small caps
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{\bfseries}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Matricat}
\subsection{Shembulli i pare, Matrica} 
\begin{equation*}
\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
  \end{array}
\right)
\end{equation*}
Kjo matrice  eshte prodhua duke perdore  komanden  pmatrix 
makro~\cite{referenca1} ne blloqe \verb|\begin{matrix}|. Disa matrica 
jane te mundshme duke perdore komandat per mjediset apo 
environment-et: \texttt{matrix}~\cite{referenca2}, 
\texttt{pmatrix}~\cite{referenca3}, \texttt{bmatrix}~\cite{referenca4}, 
\texttt{Bmatrix}~\cite{referenca5}, \texttt{vmatrix}~\cite{referenca6}, 
\texttt{Vmatrix}~\cite{referenca7}, te cilat prodhojne matricat si ne 
vijim ~\cite{referenca8}:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular*}{\displaywidth}{@{\qquad\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc@{\qquad}}
$\begin{matrix} r & s & t \\u & v & w \\x & y & z \end{matrix}$
&
$\begin{pmatrix}r & s & t\\ u & v & w\\ x & y & z\end{pmatrix}$
&
$\begin{bmatrix}r & s & t\\ u &v&w \\ x & y & z \end{bmatrix}$
\\ \addlinespace
$\begin{Bmatrix} r & s & t \\u & v & w \\x & y & z \end{Bmatrix}$
&
$\begin{vmatrix}r & s & t\\ u & v & w\\ x & y & z\end{vmatrix}$
&
$\begin{Vmatrix}r & s & t\\ u &v&w \\ x & y & z \end{Vmatrix}$
\end{tabular*}
\end{equation*}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change `\addlinespace` above into `\addlinespace[4ex]`, you get

[image]

### Some notes

Avoid things such as `{\center\section{\bfseries Matricat}}`: if you're not able to change the default setting, leave it alone and ask here. Similarly, avoid formatting instructions such as `\subsection{\bfseries Shembulli i pare, Matrica}`, because this can have unexpected consequences.

The bulk of the answer is the usage of `tabular*`, but I made other adjustments as well.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the optional argument of `\\` between rows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

{\center \section {\bfseries Matricat} }
\subsection{\bfseries Shembulli i pare, Matrica}
\begin{equation*}
  \left(\begin{array}{c}a_{11}\quad a_{12}\quad ⋯ \quad a_{1n} \\ a_{21}\quad a_{22} \quad ⋯ \quad a_{2n} \\ ⋮ \qquad ⋮ \qquad ⋱ \quad ⋮ \\ a_{n1} \quad a_{n2} \quad ⋯ \quad a_{nn} \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
Kjo matrice eshte prodhua duke perdore komanden pmatrix makro~\cite{referenca1} ne blloqe begin[matrix]. Disa matrica jane te mundshme duke perdore komandat per mjediset apo environment-et: \\ \textbf{matrix}~\cite{referenca2}, \textbf{pmatrix}~\cite{referenca3}, \textbf{bmatrix}~\cite{referenca4}, \textbf{Bmatrix}~\cite{referenca5}, \textbf{vmatrix}~\cite{referenca6}, \textbf{Vmatrix}~\cite{referenca7}, te cilat prodhojne matricat si ne vijim ~\cite{referenca8}:%
\begin{gather*}
  \begin{matrix} r & s & t \\u & v & w \\x & y & z \end{matrix}\qquad \begin{pmatrix}r\quad s\quad t\\ u\quad v\quad w\\ x\quad y\quad z\end{pmatrix} \qquad \begin{bmatrix}r & s & t\\ u &v&w \\ x & y & z \end{bmatrix}\\[6ex]
  \begin{Bmatrix}r & s & t \\u & v & w \\x & y & z \end{Bmatrix}\qquad \begin{vmatrix}r\quad s\quad t\\ u\quad v\quad w\\ x\quad y\quad z\end{vmatrix} \qquad \begin{Vmatrix}r & s & t\\ u &v&w \\ x & y & z \end{Vmatrix} \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't introduce line breaks within the `equation*` environment. So, set the collection of three matrices inside an `array`, where you can then use `\\[<len>]` to introduce a suitable space between any subsequent rows of matrices:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{equation*}
  \left(\begin{array}{ @{} *{4}{c} @{} }
    a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}
  \end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

\lipsum[1]:
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{c}
    \begin{matrix}
      r & s & t \\
      u & v & w \\
      x & y & z
    \end{matrix} \qquad
    \begin{pmatrix}
      r & s & t \\
      u & v & w \\
      x & y & z
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad
    \begin{bmatrix}
      r & s & t \\
      u & v & w \\
      x & y & z
    \end{bmatrix} \\[5\normalbaselineskip]
    \begin{matrix}
      r & s & t \\
      u & v & w \\
      x & y & z
    \end{matrix} \qquad
    \begin{pmatrix}
      r & s & t \\
      u & v & w \\
      x & y & z
    \end{pmatrix} \qquad
    \begin{bmatrix}
      r & s & t \\
      u & v & w \\
      x & y & z
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```